# debug_traceTransaction return two CALLS when it was only only one

Tags: ether, geth-debugging, internal-transactions

Here is tx: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x383753b4b7bba7d4bbdd94b1ad0c2f0ab7d6148de8178ad07eaf2cf28f57196d So we can see only one internal transfer to `0xeacd59712b496c9877244da25824b73cb5f6e94c` When I execute `debug_traceTransaction` I see 2 logs with op `CALL`:

```
{
  pc: 1584,
  op: 'CALL',
  gas: 107299,
  gasCost: 106195,
  depth: 1,
  stack: [
    '0x39125215',
    '0xf2',
    '0xeacd59712b496c9877244da25824b73cb5f6e94c',
    '0xbc0820a28ae502c',
    '0x60',
    '0x61e07423',
    '0x5ea6',
    '0x80',
    '0x27eb4bfd069ffef737e6be970d5ac91a1fc290b1a2396a4f0433396835af4c2a',
    '0xfd1e6255f1dd164665d04f3513b76345929fc440',
    '0xeacd59712b496c9877244da25824b73cb5f6e94c',
    '0xbc0820a28ae502c',
    '0x120',
    '0x0',
    '0x120',
    '0x0',
    '0x120',
    '0xbc0820a28ae502c',
    '0xeacd59712b496c9877244da25824b73cb5f6e94c',
    '0x11b90'
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  pc: 2405,
  op: 'CALL',
  gas: 143822,
  gasCost: 118215,
  depth: 1,
  stack: [
    '0x39125215',
    '0xf2',
    '0xeacd59712b496c9877244da25824b73cb5f6e94c',
    '0xbc0820a28ae502c',
    '0x60',
    '0x61e07423',
    '0x5ea6',
    '0x80',
    '0x27eb4bfd069ffef737e6be970d5ac91a1fc290b1a2396a4f0433396835af4c2a',
    '0x0',
    '0x5b6',
    '0xeacd59712b496c9877244da25824b73cb5f6e94c',
    '0x27eb4bfd069ffef737e6be970d5ac91a1fc290b1a2396a4f0433396835af4c2a',
    '0x80',
    '0x61e07423',
    '0x5ea6',
    '0x0',
    '0x0',
    '0x857',
    '0x27eb4bfd069ffef737e6be970d5ac91a1fc290b1a2396a4f0433396835af4c2a',
    '0x80',
    '0x0',
    '0xf8170b0a1ec95b48fb5d3cab031271af3f16b26fd91f4354eff88b9c3b500a51',
    '0x3a786a6a435f14c5452e613536e6f1f55478f626b254e572fdc8b01b4411bdd3',
    '0x1c',
    '0x1',
    '0x1a0',
    '0x20',
    '0x100',
    '0x80',
    '0x120',
    '0x0',
    '0x1',
    '0x1cd63'
  ]
}
```

My goal is detect when user receive ETH by internal transfer and in such case I need to understand if it was one or two transfers in fact. Why they have different gas? Whay it is not just one `CALL` op?